# Conditional transposition in awk based on column values

Tags: awk, conditional-statements, transpose

I'm trying to make the below transformation using `awk`.

Input:

```
status,parent,child,date
first,foo,bar,2019-01-01
NULL,foo,bar,2019-01-02
NULL,foo,bar,2019-01-03
last,foo,bar,2019-01-04
NULL,foo,bar,2019-01-05
blah,foo,bar,2019-01-06
NULL,foo,bar,2019-01-07
first,bif,baz,2019-01-02
NULL,bif,baz,2019-01-03
last,bif,baz,2019-01-04
```

Expected output:

```
parent,child,first,last
foo,bar,2019-01-01,2019-01-04
bif,baz,2019-01-02,2019-01-04
```

I'm pretty stumped by this problem, and haven't got anything to show yet - any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: Trivial to you :~) The approach I am trying is to create an arrany of `parent,child` then loop over each pair, printing to output col $3 or $4 the value in input $4 conditional on the value in input $1. The control flow for this is eluding me though.

Comment: Please make an attempt and add it to your question. We're happy to help you fix your coding problems, but not so fond of requests for handouts. :)

Comment: I appreciate that @ghoti - I usually do include my efforts, but this time I got stumped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ key = $2 OFS $3 }
FNR==1 { print key, "first", "last" }
$1=="first" { first[key] = $4 }
$1=="last"  { print key, first[key], $4 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
parent,child,first,last
foo,bar,2019-01-01,2019-01-04
bif,baz,2019-01-02,2019-01-04
```

If you can have a first without a last or vice-versa or they can occur out of order then include those cases in the example in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","
  print "parent,child,first,last"
}
$1=="first" || $1=="last"{
  a[$1,$2,$3]=$NF
  b[$2,$3]
}
END{
  for(i in b){
     print i,a["first",i],a["last",i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
parent,child,first,last
bif,baz,2019-01-02,2019-01-04
foo,bar,2019-01-01,2019-01-04
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                      ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","                         ##Setting Fs, OFS and SUBSEP as comma here.
  print "parent,child,first,last"           ##Printing header values as per OP request here.
}                                           ##Closing BEGIN BLOCK for this progam here.
$1=="first" || $1=="last"{                  ##Checking condition if $1 is either string first or last then do following.
  a[$1,$2,$3]=$NF                           ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1,$2,$3 and its value is $NF(last column of current line).
  b[$2,$3]                                  ##Creating an array named b whose index is $2,$3 from current line.
}                                           ##Closing main BLOCK for main program here.
END{                                        ##Starting END BLOCK for this awk program.
  for(i in b){                              ##Starting a for loop to traverse through array here.
     print i,a["first",i],a["last",i]       ##Printing variable it, array a with index of "first",i and value of array b with index of "last",i.
  }                                         ##Closing BLOCK for, for loop here.
}                                           ##Closing BLOCK for END block for this awk program here.
'  Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Why set SUBSEP? How does that help here?

Comment: @ghoti default value of SUBSEP is not a printable character

Comment: @ghoti, `SUBSEP` is a kind of separator between array's indexes example `a[$1,$2]` doesn't mean that they are separated by `,`. They will be separated by default value of `SUBSEP` which is not a printable char, so I am making it as `,` since I want to print index as variable `i` to get output like OP's(BTW index is `first` and `second`' column's values here). If I don't set it to `,` then value `bif,baz` will come like `bifbaz` etc.

Comment: Gotcha, you're hacking the output by using a separator that is printable rather than a control character (034). Clever.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 that's so so helpful, and again sorry for not providing any of my attempts! So setting `SUBSEP` is a shorthand for just including `FS` in the array itself e.g. would `b[$2,$3]` be equivalent to `b[$2 FS $3]`?

Comment: @tesolat, No, `FS` will be set for whole lines but `SUBSEP` will set separator value for array. In this case coincidentally both are same in other cases they may NOT be same and you may need to set value of `FS` differently, both are different only, lemme know if any more doubts here please.

Comment: Why pass the array to `$NF`?

Comment: @tesolat,I added a detailed explanation for my code, please go through it and lemme know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Not awk, you already have that, but here's an option in bash alone, just for kicks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A first=()

printf 'parent,child,first,last\n'

while IFS=, read pos a b date; do
  case "$pos" in
    first) first[$a,$b]=$date ;;
    last) printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$a" "$b" "${first[$a,$b]}" "$date" ;;
  esac
done < input.csv
```

Requires bash 4+ for the associative array.

Comment: That'll take hours instead of seconds (eg with awk) to run on a moderately large file.

Comment: @EdMorton .. Yup. Just thought the OP might appreciate additional perspective on the problem, since they were sufficiently stumped that they had nothing to start with.